# How to synchronize PATCH http request from multiple machines to a Single machine

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, routes, apache-camel, synchronization

I have same camel rest api on 2 different machine say A and B, at the end the 2 different machines(A and B) point to a common application server say C where update on record is performed, before performing update there are multiple get methods to collect the information
from common application server (C). (This is for common ID say 10 from both A and B)

I am in situation where I have to synchronize request coming from A and B or something like only 1 request should process at a time, once it is completed the other should start.

Below is what I have tried :

Machine A and B is having  common DB, so I have tried storing ID in db for Request A and checking if there exist same id it should wait in case of B. Once A complete it's processing ID is removed from DB and B will check at this point it will not get ID and it will start it's process.

Unfortunately the solution I have tried is not up-to the mark it seems, it will be great if you can suggest some solution over it.

PS : I am using camel route's here multiple get request are performed before performing update
So I want to make 1 request in waiting this cannot be achieved by synchronization because the machines A and B are different.

There is no such code to paste as of now

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could "synchronize" this scenario by **decoupling** the data collection from the update operation with **JMS queues**. A and B are collecting the needed data and finally producing update requests as JMS messages into the same queue.

C (or someone else) is consuming the messages and just does the update requests against C.

This asynchronous solution implies that **A and B do not need a synchronous response** for an update request.

That **changes the error handling fundamentally**. You have to handle update errors at the consumer side. When A and B successfully drop an update request on the queue they are no more responsible. If an error occurs later it does not reach them. So you need to validate data on A and B and reject the request if the data is not sufficient for an update.

On the other side, you can process requests on A and B when C is down. They don't care as long as the broker is available to drop the messages. When C is up again, it can process the queued messages.

To **strictly synchronize** on the consumer side, you simply use **only 1 consumer**.

If you use a JMS broker that supports [message groups](https://activemq.apache.org/message-groups) (for example ActiveMQ) you can even tune this scenario. Let's assume you only need to **synchronize for requests with the same ID**. In this case you set the ID as `JMSXGroupID`. Then you can use as much consumers as you like and the broker takes care that **all requests for the same ID are processed by the same consumer** (and are therefore synchronized).